# Laravel, how to change "months" language in Form::selectMonths?

Tags: php, laravel

I already build up a php file in resources/lang/en named changeMonthLanguage.php

how do I use the `Lang::get` or `trans()` in `{!!  Form::selectMonth('monthsColumn', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}`?

another questions, after the user selected the month, how do I return the result to first day of the month? For example, if the user select December, then I wanted to save the data as 1/12/2017 into table

Comment: Please this exmaple:
{!! Form::input('email', 'email', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-icon input-icon-email ' . $errors->first('email', 'has-error'), 'placeholder' => trans('validation.attributes.frontend.email')]) !!}

Comment: why dont you use javascript plugins like pick a date. http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ Its easy to implement and comes will all the bells and whistles you need

Comment: @usrNotFound i have to download it in order to use it? hmmm

Comment: go to pick a date website. They have all the instruction. you can even pull it as npm package and include it in you app.js

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i've tried yours, but only append the list in the select box...and if i use your method, it only change only 1 word...i wanted to change all the world from january to december